# Spring data Mongodb List Point Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Is it possible to do location based query in List of points in mongodb ?

Currently I am doing this:

```
@Document
public class Restaurant {

@Id
private ObjectId id;

// store locations of restaurant branches
private List<Point> locationPoints = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

The restaurants will have multiple locations and i need to find restaurant near a given Point.

```
 Point londonPoint = new Point(-0.125487, 51.508515); // london 
 List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.findBylocationPointsNear(londonPoint, new Distance(30, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
```